# Windows Login vs. AAD vs. Excel vs. Azure Functions Auth

Tags: excel, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I researched now for some time but did not find any answers for my problem.

I want to secure some Azure Functions.

That works for me if I use e.g. a Web Application I implemented. By using the token after authentication I can send it in header to Azure Functions and there configed the authentication against Azure Active Directory.

But now my challenge:

I want to send data to this REST API endpoint from an Excel VBA Makro.

But how (if possible) can I read the token I want to send to API? I guess Windows knows the token, but can I access it from Makro?

Best Regards and thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can send a request to acquire with VBA.

Just do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request) request in VBA to get access token. And then use the access token in the header of function request.